Is it worth trying to improve my lactate threshold or should I focus on VO2 max?
I have been using the Karvonen heart rate reserve formula for working out my training zones, but I suspect they are wrong, because I have run a half marathon at least three times now in zone 4 (threshold) throughout.  This implies that my lactate threshold must be above about 160 bpm, but as my maximum heart rate (highest rate observed in fast 5ks and Cooper tests) is only about 175, this suggests there isn't much room for improvement.  160bpm would be ~91.5% of my maximum heart rate, which I gather is already above what would be expected of a well-trained runner (which I am not, I've only been running for about two years).
My pace isn't too bad for someone in their mid-fifties (PRs approximately 22:20 for 5k, 47:20 for 10k and 1:55:00 for half Marathon), but definitely nothing special, so I hope there is still some room for improvement there.
Is it likely that I am already around my physical maximum for lactate threshold, and reached the point of diminishing returns already, and I perhaps should focus on other things (VO2 max?) if I want to be fitter and run faster?   Or should I just continue doing a mixture of slow, fast, interval and threshold runs?  I don't particularly want to run a Marathon or very long distances, I just wouldn't be able to fit in the required training, so half-Marathon is the longest distance of interest at the moment.
I think I need to clarify here.  As I understand it, there are different physiological aspects to running fast, one of which is lactate tolerance, another might be maximum ability to utilise oxygen during exercise (but there may be others).  What I am asking is basically whether I should shift focus away from activities that are likely to improve my (apparently already very high) lactate threshold (e.g. tempo and threshold runs) and do something different instead (and if so, what).  This is a separate issue from running economy, which is something I can work on at the same time (again, AIUI).

Anecdotal, hence a comment and not an answer: I run [sic!] into the same problem, with there being a very narrow band between zone 3 and upper limit (about 10 higher each as I'm younger). For me, this is due to a good but not very good VO2max coupled with a very high lactate tolerance.

@PhilipKlöcking cheers, that indeed sounds very similar.  My VO2 max (estimated by my watch) has been 46 or 47 for most of this year (but headed downwards as I have strained my Achilles again - despite your good advice!).  So good, but not very good.  So perhaps it isn't that the lactate levels are not high, just that I can tolerate it?

Lactate tolerance refers mainly to the lactate metabolism, ie. to how well oxygenation of the muscles works and how fast the liver can deal with the lactate. Thus, it is about lactate turnover, not levels. When local and/or global lactate levels reach a certain threshold, there's no "tolerating" it because biochemical processes just start to slow down period.

I am not a fan of VO2 max as a performance metric, it's more of an indicator of potential. You can up your VO2 simply by losing weight. If you want to go down that path, vV02 (Velocity at VO2 max) is a much better number to chase. Admittedly, this was late 80's before a lot of these metrics became widely available, but I had a very successful (scholarship athlete) career in x-country without ever knowing any of this other than a couple lab tests here and there.

@JohnP the VO2 max I had in mind was the performance based estimate you get from the Cooper test or a watch, rather than lab measurements, so they are performance metrics.  Perhaps I should make regular estimates of vV02 via 2k time trials as well as Cooper tests, but I am really asking about physiological development rather than economy/technique improvement.

No, they aren't. They are a test of fitness, which can be wholly unrelated to performance. And if your economy/technique sucks, you will get much more bang for your buck improving that. If you've ever seen Chariots of Fire, you'd have seen an example. "Yer overstridin. Knocks ye back" and "I can find you another 2 yards" which was all done through technique, not fitness.

FYI, I'm also not a fan of training by HR. HR is a downstream metric, and can be affected by food intake, rest, any number of factors.

@JohnP "No, they aren't. They are a test of fitness, which can be wholly unrelated to performance. " are you saying that seeing how far you can run in 12 minutes (the Cooper test) is not a measure of performance?

The cooper run test is somewhat of a performance test, but it doesn't really indicate that you will succeed in other athletics, or even longer running events. FA (English football) is phasing it out for refs, as it doesn't accurately predict performance in a match. You can be very fit, ace the Cooper and then be unable to complete a tennis match. Or a 10k. Or ride a bike 20 miles.  It's a measure of how well you perform on the test, and its a level of fitness but for other things its a predictor of potential success.

@JohnP "but it doesn't really indicate that you will succeed in other athletics, or even longer running events" well of course it doesn't - I don't think anybody is claiming otherwise.  However, surely that also applies to vVO2, which apparently can be estimated by a 2k time trial, which means it is similar to the Cooper test, but over 2k rather than approx. 3k.  Unless you can afford lab measurements (I can't), I don't think either estimate is going be superior to the other, and you would still need to consider other factors (e.g. lactate threshold) to maximise performance over, say > 5k?

The Karvonen Formula
I think the first thing to understand is that the Karvonen formula is designed as a general prescription to help individuals optimize their heart health and overall fitness.  That is exactly what it has done for you. One of the natural consequences is that you are able to run pretty fast for your age. If your main goal is to have optimal health and you are content with being able to run well, I would suggest maintaining your current training regimen.
Fitness Runner vs Racer
If you're thinking you want to become a racer, we need to be clear.  Not everyone who runs is a racer.  Not everyone who can be a racer wants to be a racer. Many who try to become racers don't enjoy it.  You need to decide if you want to be a racer or you just want to be in good shape and able to run.  From what you have described, you have the potential to become a great race runner, but you need to be sure that's the path you want to follow.
A racer's mentality is that fast race times are the primary goal and improved health is a byproduct. So you would shift your training from the improve-heart-health-and-general-fitness approach to a race-as-fast-as-possible approach. That may seem like either a subtle nuance or two ways of saying the same thing, but it's major shift in mindset. Your goals are different and the purpose for each run changes.
Race based training
So where do you get a training plan for race running? You can download a training plan from one of hundreds of sites. The upside is they are free and you can start today, but there are downsides as well. Finding a training plan that way is like finding a spouse through a dating app.  You can't easily tell which one is a good match from the profile pic. You don't want to get 2 months into a training plan, only to find out it isn't right for you.  There are a lot of factors that need to be considered, well understood, and correctly applied for each individual to optimize results.
A better approach is to do your own study and design your own plan. In my opinion, Jack Daniel's VDOT formula and tables are a great place to start. I would recommend the book "Daniel's Running Formula" as a good resource to understand the science and fundamentals of run-specific training.  It's probably worth reading and thinking about before you make any major adjustments to your training. If you read the book and decide you want to move forward, you will have the knowledge to design a customized training program that will help you run faster races and peak for your target race.  Not only will you achieve better results faster, but there is an increased sense of accomplishment when it's your plan that leads to those results.
The Decision
After reading the book, you may realize that the faster times aren't worth the extra effort. It's better to reach that conclusion after a few hours of reading than to figure it out after months or years of adjusted training. I am currently running for fitness after more than 10 years of running for times.  Life got busy, so I had to simplify. But at heart, I am a runner and a racer and as soon as life slows down, I will be designing my own plan to get age-group awards in local 10Ks and qualify for Boston again. It's not for everyone and not always the right time for everyone, but if you're into it, peaking in your target race with a new PR is absolutely exhilarating!

Thanks for the answer.  I am not a racer in the sense of wanting to race against other people (I don't have the genetics for that to be worthwhile) but I am interested in racing against my former self and setting PRs and getting faster over a range of distances.  I'll get a copy of the book and give it some thought.  " There are a lot of factors " indeed, whether I was near my LT optimal was the factor I was primarily interested in here.
